# Back to Javascript from Coffeescript default on yeoman webapp

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, yeoman

I am a yeoman newbie and I accidentally installed Sass/CoffeeScript which now defaults to changes being built from the CoffeeScript file. I would like to go back to working with the JS file i.e.

```
    scripts/main.js
```

Is there a flag / value that I can change in something like Gruntfile.js to go back to Javascript mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about an easier solution, but here's mine:

Create two identical scaffolds with yeoman: one with Sass/CoffeeScript support, the other without. Next, compare created project structures recursively (I recommend using `meld`). You'll find out that the only actual differences lie in `Gruntfile` - apply them in your original project.